# Causality of effects of alcohol to the brain

Tags: philosophy-of-science, causality, history

According to Judea Pearl's book [The book of Why](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/WHY/) it took several decades to establish a scientific consensus that smoking causes lung cancer (amongst other diseases).

I was wondering whether it took a similar amount of time to see the harmful effects of long-term alcohol consumption to our cognitive abilities? If not, why were the adverse effects of alcohol seen so much clearly than the effects of smoking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judea Pearl's book on causality[1] was written precisely due to such type of issue, mainly to define a method to establish the causal relationship of a fact of perception with another (I think he says somewhere that people did not believe the causal link between vaccines and sickness, so he tried to formalize the process to establish causality with such book). The common problem is to establish a set of conditions, excluding all possible subjective elements, in order to define a context that allows using math to establish causality.

For example, I can consider that the alcohol is bad to the brain if the brain loses 20% more of cells within a period X, on two test groups performing exactly the same activities, having the same health parameters, along two days of test, with one group drinking 10ml of alcohol per hour and the other drinking water. But as you see, that's highly subjective.

From a philosophical point of view (complex systems theory/chaos theory), ultimately, every event is related to all other events (check the Butterfly Effect [2]). In such case, if you blink and the day before you cut your hair, you can state that there's a causal relationship between blinking and having the hair cut. Although such approach is strictly true, it is useless to define causality.

From another point of view (Hume, empiricism), causality just a mental phenomenon. If you put the kettle on the stove and then it boils, you feel a causal relationship, but it is just than an expectation. There's no formal reason to assume that the water will boil. According to Hume, causality is nothing more than *custom and habit*.

So, in the case of alcohol, there are lots of tests establishing the causal relationship between alcohol and brain damage, within the conditions of a common human experience. Being picky about the formalities implies entering in such complex philosophical problems, so it is usually necessary to accept some compromise (e.g. if the majority of studies relating alcohol to brain damage say alcohol is bad, one can assume it is bad).

[1] http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/book-toc.html

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect